# Select all except $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have the following bit of code

```
$('.radio-box').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.container-radio-box').find('.select').removeClass('state-active');
}
```

and I'm trying to get it so that it will find the clicked `.radio-box` element, look for it's containing element — `.container-radio-box` — and then remove the active state from any `.select` elements inside it.

I have a feeling I could use something along the lines of

```
$('.radio-box').not(this).each(function() {
```

However it's a little more complicated because there are numerous `.container-radio-box` elements and they all need to be treated individually. E.g. only the `.select` elements that are within the containing div of the clicked `.radio-box` should be modified by the script.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

**Edit:**
I've modified my script like so:

```
// radio-box
$('.radio-box').click(function() {

    $(this).parents('.container-radio-box').find('.radio-box').removeClass('state-active');

    var el = this;
        $(this).parents('.container-radio-box')
                .find('.select')
                .filter(function(index){
                    return this != el;
                                })
                .removeClass('state-active');


    $(this).find('input').prop( "checked", true );
    $(this).addClass('state-active');

});
```

and have also uploaded the page here so you can see how it works — http://www.mattpealing.co.uk/_concept/brdcr/form/

I'm trying to get it so that the `.select` elements in the left column can stay selected *until* one of the other columns is selected, in which case the active state is removed.

But it seems that clicking the left column is also removing the active states from the `.select` elements contained inside it

Comment: It appears that Burimi's answer is perfect, unless we're missing something. If it doesn't work, please include some sample HTML which would help a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let jQuery do the hard work for you - select the siblings of the clicked `.radio-box` and only search for `.select` elements within those:

```
$('.radio-box').click(function() {

    // Deselect all radio boxes
    $(this).parents('.container-radio-box').find('.radio-box').removeClass('state-active');

    // Remove active state from inner options in other radio boxes
    $(this).siblings()
        .find('.select')
        .removeClass('state-active');

    // Select this radio box
    $(this).find('input').prop( "checked", true );
    $(this).addClass('state-active');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the collection and compare the DOM elements :

```
var el = this;
    $(this).parents('.container-radio-box')
            .find('.select')
            .filter(function(index){
                return this != el;
                            })
            .removeClass('state-active');
```

Comment: thank you! unfortunately it still doesn't appear to be working, I've now edited my question and also posted an example of the page online

Comment: This won't work: it's selecting all `.select` elements in all the `td`s, including the one clicked on, and then trying to filter those `.select` elements by comparing against the `td`. See my answer below